# threadscope installed via cabal, but cannot be called from terminal

Tags: haskell

Hi I've installed threadscope from cabal, yet I cannot call it from terminal (i.e. -bash: threadscope: command not found) how do I get terminal to see threadscope even while it can see other cabal installations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your using a Unix-like system like Linux or Mac:

This is because the cabal executable directory is not part of your path. You can either:

1. `cabal exec threadscope`
2. Add `~/.cabal/bin` to your `$PATH`. For example if you are using bash add the following line to your `~/.bashrc`:

   ```
   export PATH=$PATH:~/.cabal/bin
   ```

   or append the `:~/.cabal/bin` to such a line that may already be in place.